# comma separated portlet preferences

Tags: websphere, portlet, websphere-7

I am using same portlet for different purposes by copying the portlet. I have give the preference as comma separated like `xxxx,yyyy` for datapoint preference. According to the [portletAPI](http://www.bluesunrise.com/portlet-api/javax/portlet/PortletPreferences.html) `getValue()` return the first associated value. I only get `xxxx` value when retrieve it. I am wondering how to get the `yyyy` value.

Answer (score 1):

The portlet API link you reference has a `getValues()` method as well. The comma separated preferences should be returned in the array from `getValues()`.